# property disabled for Form Control remove the data

Tags: angular

I create a FormGroup which contains a FormControl and I want for some value apply the property "disabled: true/false" but if I edit one of the values the other is empty...

```
return this.formBuilder.group({
  civilite: new FormControl({value: personne.civilite || '', disabled: personne.civilite }),
  situationfamiliale: new FormControl({value: personne.situationfamiliale || '', disabled: personne.situationfamiliale }),
});

<div class="col-md-6 col-xl">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label for="situationFamiliale">{{'situation' | translate}}</label>
            <ngx-select id="situationFamiliale" [items]="familyStatus" formControlName="situationFamiliale"
                [allowClear]="true" placeholder="{{'CHOOSE_LBL' | translate}}"
                noResultsFound="{{'NO_RESULTS_FOUND_LBL' | translate}}" > 
                <ng-template ngx-select-option-selected ngx-select-option let-option let-text="text" >
                    {{option.data.text | translate}}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-select>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="civilite">{{'civilite' | translate}}</label>
            <ngx-select id="civilite" [items]="civilities" formControlName="civilite" [allowClear]="true"
                placeholder="{{'CHOOSE_LBL' | translate}}" noResultsFound="{{'NO_RESULTS_FOUND_LBL' | translate}}" >
                <ng-template ngx-select-option-selected ngx-select-option let-option let-text="text" >
                    {{option.data.text | translate}}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[the value before i edit the other value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCvQk.png)

[the value after I change the other value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qmBI.png)

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Post the HTML code as well.

Comment: I don't understand so much the question, but remember that if you has one FormControl disabled, you need use `myForm.getRawValue()` not only `myForm.value` to get all the values, see https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue

Comment: Eliseo if i use getRawValue he return null

Comment: How do you edit personne ? how do you update this object in your code ?

Comment: it's work :D i juste not use the getRawValue in the good file.. thanks for your help guys !